# Odd behavior using BackgroundWorker with Thread.Sleep

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have never seen anything before like this.  I am using Visual Studio 2015 preview and verified it on Visual Studio 2012.

```
    private void InitializeBackgroundWorkers()
    {
        MONITOR.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        MONITOR.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        MONITOR.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(MONITOR_DoWork);
        MONITOR.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(MONITOR_ProgressChanged);
        MONITOR.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(MONITOR_WorkCompleted);

        MONITOR2.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        MONITOR2.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        MONITOR2.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(MONITOR2_DoWork);
        MONITOR2.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(MONITOR2_ProgressChanged);
    }
```

The issue occurs in the DoWork Event for a BackgroundWorker. Obviously I have made a mistake somehow.

```
    private void MONITOR2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (CONTINUE)
        {
            oldClockNow = clockNow;
            //BP1
            clockThen = RunTime.ElapsedTicks;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            //BP2
            clockNow = RunTime.ElapsedTicks;

            TS = RunTime.Elapsed;

            MONITOR2.ReportProgress(0);
        }

        RunTime.Stop();
    }
```

The issue is I noticed for various reasons that ClockThen was always "newer" than ClockNow. I ignored it till now and altered my code to utilize the ClockThen as the ClockNow and vice versa.

I finally had time to look at the code closer with breakpoints. I placed one at clockThen assignment, one at clockNow assignment, and one inside the ReportProgress Event, so I can stop one more time outside of the MONITOR2 stack.

Note: I am using ProgressChanged as a way to update the main UI.

```
    private void MONITOR2_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        double calcClockOld = (((double)oldClockNow) * (1F / Stopwatch.Frequency));
        double calcClockThen = (((double)clockThen) * (1F / Stopwatch.Frequency));
        double calcClockNow = (((double)clockNow) * (1F / Stopwatch.Frequency));

        //BP3
        tbxClockDrift.Text = ((calcClockThen - calcClockNow) * 1000000).ToString("0.#####\\ µs");

        string timestamp = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", TS.Hours, TS.Minutes, TS.Seconds);

        tbxTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        tbxRunTime.Text = timestamp;
        tbxTimeZone.Text = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToUniversalTime(DateTime.Now).ToString();
    }
```

The third breakpoint is at tbxClockDrift.Text assignment.

So I have 3 breakpoints total, but when stepped through the code, BP1 always executes twice and I believe its why the value keeps being higher!

So the step through I see this a phantom breakpoint:

Step Through 1, clockThen = RunTime.ElapsedTicks;

Step Through 2, jumps to clockNow = Runtime.ElapsedTicks; after sleeping for a second.

***Step Through 3, back to clockThen assignment (verified new values!)***

Step Through 4, tbxClockDrift.Text assignment!

Why is clockThen receiving a second assignment!?

Comment: How are you setting up the BackgroundWorker?

Comment: It really sounds like you have more than one background worker running and the debugger switches between the two when you step over the Sleep call.

Comment: Your code is not thread-safe, the ProgressChanged event handler runs an arbitrary time *after* your worker calls ReportProgress().  That means that your event handler cannot use the clockThen/Now variables.  It does not have to, use the ReportProgress(int, object) overload instead, that allows you to pass a value to your event handler.

Comment: Added the BackgroundWorker initialization code.

@Hans
Wait, you mean ReportProgress() is not sequentially processed?

The logic of my code, I figured was inherently thread-safe, as those variables are only read after ReportProcess() was initiated, which means that they were not being accessed at that time.  If that's the case, that would be my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a little more obvious if I rewrite your method a bit to make the sleep the last thing that happens inside the while loop. This code behaves exactly the same as your current code.

```
private void MONITOR2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    if(CONTINUE)
    {
        oldClockNow = clockNow;
        //BP1
        clockThen = RunTime.ElapsedTicks;
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        while (true)
        {
            //BP2
            clockNow = RunTime.ElapsedTicks;

            TS = RunTime.Elapsed;

            MONITOR2.ReportProgress(0);
            if(!CONTINUE)
                break;

            oldClockNow = clockNow;
            //BP1
            clockThen = RunTime.ElapsedTicks;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
    RunTime.Stop();
}
```

So `clockThen` is not receiving a 2nd assignment it is just `clockThen` is the last thing you do before you sleep. Also the processing of `ReportProgress` does not have to happen right at the time you call the function, calling the function just queues up the event to be fired next time the UI can get around to it.

So what is happening is you assign `clockNow`, you queue up a progress report, you assign a value to `clockThen`, finally you start to sleep. While you are sleeping `ReportProgress` finally gets around to running and you get the value of `clockThen` you assigned from right before you slept.

Comment: This works but it's like Hans Passant said, it isn't necessarily thread-safe or executing in a controlled order.  I thought BackgroundWorker_DoWork was temporarily paused while BackgroundWorker_ReportProgress executed, finished, and returned to the DoWork section.  That apparently is not the case; DoWork continues executing asynchronously.  It continues running through its infinite loop which explains why the assignment order quickly gets out of hand.  There is no phantom breakpoint, the loop is just starting over before the code the ReportProgress function is even reached/executed.

Comment: @RagingCain I am not fixing anything in my answer, I just explain what is going wrong and you can solve the problem however you want.

Comment: @ScottChamerlain Sorry about that, I was a tad rushed when I read it before.  I appreciate the extra information.